# Python Select Specific Row and Column from CSV file

Tags: python

I want to print specific row and column from a csv file.
csv file look like,

R,IMSI,DATE FIRST EVENT,TIME FIRST EVENT,DATE LAST EVENT,TIME LAST EVENT,DC(HHMMSS),NC,VOLUME,SDR
R
C,634012007277489,20221122,150025,20221122,150025,711,1,0,294
C,634012031576061,20221122,150859,20221122,151738,905,3,0,1597
C,634012045006518,20221122,144022,20221122,144022,902,1,0,368
R
R
R,END OF REPORT
T,18

Output should be look like,

C,634012007277489,20221122,150025,20221122,150025,711,1,0,294 C,634012031576061,20221122,150859,20221122,151738,905,3,0,1597 C,634012045006518,20221122,144022,20221122,144022,902,1,0,368

Comment: post your current code

Comment: Check your file data. Last line has more columns than header.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pandas` (you need to install it first by `pip install pandas` in the terminal).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(fullpath.csv)
x = df[column_name].iloc[row_number]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reading it with `pandas.read_csv()`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skipfooter=1, header=1)
df.iloc[row_number,column_number]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .iat too.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("example.csv", delimiter =",")

for row in range(len(df)):
    for column in range(len(df.columns)):
        print(df.iat[row, column])
```